# Memory Stream Inserting image into DB

Tags: c#, sql-server

I will need your help in solving this piece.

I am trying to insert this image *alb.picture* into the *DB*. To use `MemoryStream`, am I missing some read here.

The code dosen't return any errors but it just inserts *0X00000* and retrieving `(select * ....)`, it shows a blank in the grid.. The rest of the fields, `created_date` and `updated_date` are fine during grid dipslay.

```
foreach (Album alb in albms.data)
{
    alb.picture = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + alb.id + 
        "/picture/?access_token=" + Token;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(1000);
    string sfn = alb.picture;

    m_lImageFileLength = alb.picture.Length;
    m_barrImg = new Byte[Convert.ToInt32(m_lImageFileLength)];

    ms.Read(m_barrImg, 0, (int)m_lImageFileLength);
    objBLL.insert_FacebookPhotos(Convert.ToInt64(ui.id), m_barrImg, 
       alb.created_time.ToString(), alb.updated_time.ToString());


}
```

Thanks a lot
SC

Comment: You are reading **from** the (empty) `MemoryStream`, into the (empty) new `byte[]`). Where is the actual data?

Comment: Also; in the first line you assign a `string` to `alb.picture`; then later you seem to stream the `Length` of this ***string*** as the size of the data (see: `m_lImageFileLength = alb.picture.Length;`). Again: where is the actual data?

Comment: You aren't actually reading the image from the server. Read through your code and 'run' in on paper, write out what each line is doing and you'll see where you are failing. Then look at the HTTPWebRequest and HTTPWebResponse objects to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing from an empty MemoryStream. First, you might want to remove the 1000 capacity in instantiating it.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
```

It looks like the actual stream is in `alb.picture`. Depending on the type of this object, you would want to convert it to `byte[]` first. Then **write** the `byte[]` (instead of reading it) onto the MemoryStream ms:

```
ms.Write(b, 0, b.Length); // where b is your byte[]
```

There are many ways to convert to `byte[]` depending on the type of object you are working on.

Alternatively, if the file is an [HttpPostedFileBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) you can access the `Stream` directly by its property `InputStream`.